# Align photo in Powerpoint slide using Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, powerpoint

Im trying to align photos in Powerpoint using AppleScript and cannot find the correct syntax.

`set theMedia to make new picture at end with properties {file name:theMediaFile, lock aspect ratio:true, top:0, width:1280, height:720}`

I tried

`distribute theMedia distribute type distribute horizontally with relative to slide`

But no joy

How do set the image to be in the centre of the slide OR distributed horizontally?

Thanks
Adam.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to get the `align` or `distribute` functions to work in this case. They both seem to need `shape ranges` for input (not individual shapes), and I can't quite see how to construct a shape range from an individual shape.

However, it's easy enough to center the picture the old-fashioned way, by subtracting half the picture width/height from the center point of the slide and setting that as the picture origin:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    (* 
        'thePic' and 'theSlide' are references to the picture 
        and the slide, respectively.
     *)
    set {slideHeight, slideWidth} to get {height, width} of custom layout of theSlide
    set {picHeight, picWidth} to get {height, width} of thePic
    set XPos to slideWidth / 2 - picWidth / 2
    set YPos to slideHeight / 2 - picHeight / 2
    tell thePic
        set {left position, top} to {XPos, YPos}
    end tell
end tell
```